# Publicly Available NEURON models

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, computational-modeling

NEURON is a software package for simulating neurons and networks in great detail. Although it's quite easy to find papers that use NEURON with [a simple Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?as_ylo=2015&hl=en&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=1,5&cites=16673989093981586499&scipsc=), is there some way to find which models are publicly available? For example, some repository of NEURON models and their associated publications?

If there is no standard, an answer with a few examples of recent (last 10 years) publications with a freely available NEURON model would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A repository of publicly available NEURON models can be found on [ModelDB](https://senselab.med.yale.edu/modeldb/) by filtering for [Models that contain the Modeling Application: NEURON](https://senselab.med.yale.edu/ModelDB/ModelList.cshtml?id=1882).